# Different ways of evaluating $n!$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've recently managed to prove the following result and was hoping to know if it already exists? $ \def\lf{\left\lfloor}   \def\rf{\right\rfloor}$

$$ \ln(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^{p_k < n}\left( \sum_{r=1}^\infty  r \lf \frac{n}{p_k^r} \rf\right)\ln p_k = \sum_{k=1}^{p_k < n} \lf \frac{n}{p_k} \rf  \ln p_k + \ln{\lf \frac{n}{p_k} \rf}! $$

where $n$ is any integer and $p_k$ is the k'th prime.

### Questions

Do these equations already exist? Can this be used to show any non-trivial result?

Comment: Does' nt it follow from [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicity_of_Prime_Factor_in_Factorial), applying logarithm ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, (I think so) but thats only one of the equations ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equation is wrong. The correct exponent of prime $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!$ is given by [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula):

$$\nu_p(n!)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^r} \right\rfloor$$

Thus, taking the logarithm, and the sum on $p$ running on prime $p\leq n$,

$$\log(n!)=\sum_{p\leq n}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^r}\right\rfloor\right)\log(p)$$

Your second equation is also wrong. For instance,

$$\log(5!)=\log120 \neq \sum_{k=1}^{p_k < n} \lfloor \frac{n}{p_k} \rfloor  \ln p_k + \ln{\lfloor \frac{n}{p_k} \rfloor}!=[2\log2+\log(2!)]+[\log3+\log(1!)]=\log24$$

Comment: I'm sorry but for a second I accidentally  typed that formula ... Hopefully it is correct now ...